# PostgreSQL: Set two timestamps equal to one another. One of them has a trigger associated to it

Tags: postgresql, triggers

Suppose you have a `table` with two timestamptz fields, `created` and `updated`.

`table` has a trigger like the following:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trig_table_on_update
BEFORE UPDATE ON table
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE func_table_on_update();
```

`func_table_on_update` is defined like the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func_table_on_update()
RETURNS trigger AS
$$
BEGIN
    NEW.updated = current_timestamp;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$
```

How can I set `created := updated` from within another function? The problem is `created` is being set to `OLD.updated` and then on commit `OLD.updated` gets overwritten with `current_timestamp`. I need to maintain equality between the two after commit but they cannot *always* be set to the same time.

For example,

Initial state:

```
created            |updated            |
-------------------|-------------------|
2018-10-09 15:59:23|2018-11-12 16:00:22|
```

After update:

```
created            |updated            |
-------------------|-------------------|
2018-11-12 16:00:22|2019-01-09 16:00:22|
```

Desired state:

```
created            |updated            |
-------------------|-------------------|
2018-11-12 16:00:22|2018-11-12 16:00:22|
```

Comment: With "other function" you mean an other trigger function called from another update trigger on the same table?

Comment: Just a standard function such as func_table_setTimestampsEqual(id). Not involving another trigger.

Comment: Hmm, not sure if I get it... you want to update `created` to the current value of `updated` but the problem is, that the trigger fires and both columns end up to have the current time in them instead of the value `updated` had before?

Comment: created is being set to OLD.updated and updated is being set to current_timestamp. Leaving them unequal. I pretty much want to ignore the trigger when I call this function func_table_setTimestampsEqual(). Would adding a check to the trigger such as, IF NEW.updated IS NULL then proceed as normal work? Otherwise, leave the OLD.updated untouched. That way I can say UPDATE table SET (created, updated) = (updated, updated) in this other function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trigger should be defined with the condition:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trig_table_on_update
BEFORE UPDATE ON my_table
FOR EACH ROW 
WHEN (NEW.created = OLD.created)
EXECUTE PROCEDURE func_table_on_update();
```

Also, add the statement in the trigger function:

```
    NEW.created = OLD.updated;
```

Now a transaction may look like this:

```
BEGIN;

UPDATE my_table
SET some_column = 'new value'
-- don't set created here!
WHERE id = 1;

SELECT *
FROM my_table;
-- here created <> updated

UPDATE my_table
SET created = updated
WHERE id = 1;
-- the trigger won't be fired

SELECT *
FROM my_table;
-- here created = updated

COMMIT;
```

Comment: Adding the condition to the trigger is a good idea and would work for this use case. However, NEW.created = OLD.updated cannot be added to the trigger function because there are instances where we want to keep the created timestamp but change the updated timestamp. For example, if we had a quantity field, any update to that should be reflected by the updated timestamp but since we're dealing with the same item, the created timestamp should remain the same.

Comment: Thank you for the help.

Comment: The assignment could be conditional, e.g. `if new.item_id <> old.item_id then ...`